# Can't find UIA element with FindFirst method (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ui-automation

I have an application where I can find its text-boxes when they have focus with VBA UIAutomation via the `GetFocusedElement` method, which should indicate that they are detectable by UIAutomation, but I cannot find them with `FindFirst` or `FindAll` methods, as demonstrated in the following code:

```
Public Wnd As IUIAutomationElement
Public Element As IUIAutomationElement
Public H_wnd As Long, PropValue(30003 To 30005)
Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub GetFocused()
  Tasks(MyApp).Activate
  H_wnd = GetForegroundWindow
  Set Element = UIauto.GetFocusedElement
  For i = 30003 To 30005 'ControlType, ?, Name
    PropValue(i) = Element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(i)
    'works good
    Debug.Print PropValue(i)
  Next
End Sub

Sub FindElement()
  Set Wnd = UIauto.ElementFromHandle(ByVal H_wnd)
  For i = 30003 To 30005
    'searching with the previously saved property values
    Debug.Print Wnd.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, _
      UIauto.CreatePropertyCondition(i, PropValue(i))) Is Nothing
    'prints True to all
  Next
End Sub
```

The first Sub successfully finds the focused element, and prints its properties to the immediate pane. But the second Sub finds nothing, and prints `True` to all inquiries. That doesn't change if I replace `TreeScope_Descendants` with any of the other values of `TreeScope`.

So is there a possibility to find those elements without them being in focus? I'm trying to them by their names or properties, not by getting the focused control, because when I will use this code they will not be focused.